# Why wrong datetime order in Zedgraph

Tags: zedgraph

I have the following code to plot value

```
StockPointList spl = new StockPointList();   
 for (int i = 0; i < dtTable.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
     dtDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dtTable.Rows[i]["DateTime"]);               
    XDate xDate = new XDate(dtDate.Year, dtDate.Month, dtDate.Day, dtDate.Hour, dtDate.Minute, dtDate.Second);
    double x = xDate.XLDate;                
    double open = Convert.ToDouble(dtTable.Rows[i]["BarOpen"]);
    double close = Convert.ToDouble(dtTable.Rows[i]["BarClose"]);
    double hi = Convert.ToDouble(dtTable.Rows[i]["BarHigh"]);
    double low = Convert.ToDouble(dtTable.Rows[i]["BarLow"]);                

    StockPt pt = new StockPt(x, hi, low, open, close, 100000);           
    pt.ColorValue = close > prevClose ? 2 : 1;
    spl.Add(pt);

    prevClose = close;
    open = close;      
}
myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.DateAsOrdinal;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy\nHH:MM:ss";
```

The column type of "DateTime" in the datatable is of "DateTime" format. I have also used a dataview to sort "DateTime" column. 
When I plot to ZedGraph, its getting plotted in correct datetime order but the values that are plotted in the X-axis is in wrong order. 
[image]
Any idea to resolve this?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this ?

Comment: Nope. No way out. Any idea? @Thomas

Comment: Could you provide the data you works with ?